# Llamar una funcion ng-click dentro de una directiva

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas

Tengo el siguiente problema, he creado la siguiente directiva:

```
appController.directive('erCustomerror', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            clickOn: '&',
            textoVariable: '=texto'
        },
        template: '<li><strong>{{textoVariable}}</strong></li>' +
            '<p class="error-server">' +
            '<strong>Upps!</strong><br>' +
            'Tuvimos un problema<br>Vuelve a intentarlo<br>' +
            '<a href="" ><img src="img/icon-actualizar.png" width="24" ng-click="clickOn()"></a>' +
            '</p>'
    };
})
```

y en el html esta declarado de la siguiente forma:

```
 <div class="lista-col" ng-show="ocultarErrorPost">
        <er-Customerror texto="valorDirectivePost" clickOn="refreshPortlet()"></er-Customerror>
 </div>
```

y en el controller tengo el siguiente `$scope.refreshPortlet` que quiero ejecutar cuando le doy clic a la imagen actualizar como esta en el el ejemplo.

Mi controller va de la siguiente manera

```
appController.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){
   $scope.refreshPortlet = function(){
       console.log("Haz Algo");
   }
});
```

por favor alguien que me pueda ayudar, ya que creo suporner que estoy haciendo bien, o no se que estoy haciendo mal.
gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas usando mal el *name-casing* de los atributos.

Si en tu `$scope` isolado tienes algo como

```
scope: {
    clickOn: '&',
    textoVariable: '=texto'
}
```

Esto se traducirá en los atributos `click-on` y `texto-variable`, tu tienes `clickOn` y por lo tanto no se bindea correctamente.

La regla es simple, en el `$scope` se usa [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) o sea comienza con minúsculas y divide las palabras usando mayúsculas en la primer letra y sin dejar espacios.

Ej. `esteEsMiEjemploDePropiedad`

En el DOM se usa [kebab-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case), pon todo en minúsculas y divide las palabras reemplazando el espacio con un guión.

Ej. `este-es-mi-ejemplo-de-propiedad`

Chequea el ejemplo funcionando

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('erCustomerror', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      clickOn: '&',
      textoVariable: '=texto'
    },
    template: '<li><strong>{{textoVariable}}</strong></li>' +
      '<p class="error-server">' +
      '<strong>Upps!</strong><br>' +
      'Tuvimos un problema<br>Vuelve a intentarlo<br>' +
      '<a href="" ><img src="img/icon-actualizar.png" width="24" ng-click="clickOn()"></a>' +
      '</p>'
  }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.refreshPortlet = function() {
    console.log("Haz Algo");
  }
})
```

```css
.error-server {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(220, 61, 76, 1);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.error-server a {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="lista-col">
    <er-customerror texto="valorDirectivePost" click-on="refreshPortlet()"></er-customerror>
  </div>
</div>
```